# Unable to Install Qt using the online installer

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I am trying to install Qt using *Qt online installer*; the loader keeps on coming for few minutes as shown in the image below:

[image: preparing meta info download]

Then I get the following error:

[image: Error Image]

> Cannot retreive remote tree

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fairly simple, the server is down, and it's in the process of being fixed.

See [Qt Mailing List: *download.qt.io is down*](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2021-January/036241.html).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to set up Qt Creator on Mac, if you are facing any network errors:

- Download the Qt installer DMG file.
- Open the DMG file.
- Move the `.app` file to the Desktop.
- Open the terminal, go to desktop, and run the following command:

  ```
  sudo open qt-unified-macOS-x64-4.6.1-online.app --args --mirror http://qt.mirror.constant.com
  ```

  For Linux:

  ```
  sh ./qt-unified-installer-name --mirror http://qt.mirror.constant.com
  ```